# link says "PAGE NOT FOUND"

Tags: support, broken-link, question-lists

When i click on questions button i see list of question. after that when i click on this question: [how-do-i-find-the-avg-of-a-column-in-postgres-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906122/how-do-i-find-the-avg-of-a-column-in-postgres-sql) i see **Page Not Found**. that is page is removed or question is deleted or closed.
But if so then why i see question link in list question. the link should also be removed from there.

Why the link is still there in question list??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions that have been recently deleted may not be reflected in question lists immediately, as there may be out-of-date caches showing the question still in the list. It should disappear on its own in time.

Answer (score -1):

I can tell by the answering is that the post was delete.

I think the bug should be fixed now.